# Not seeing minimize/open option on Remote desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote, remote-connection

I have been getting a small bar on top mid of the remote desktop when I connect to a remote desktop. This option helps to minimize the remote desktop and work on my local machine/ reopen the remote machine from my local system.

I have been working on a remote desktop and by mistake I clicked somewhere on the top option and it lost that option bar from remote desktop. So, if I open any remote connection, it will be in full screen and I need to scroll down to see remote desktop's status bar. Please help me to find that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source [Remote Desktop Services Shortcut Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd>
>
> Switches the client between full-screen mode and
>   window mode.

...

> Note that on an NEC98, the following shortcut keys are different:
>
> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd> is replaced by <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: Hi David, I don't have break key in my laptop. I tried with f12 but I couldn't see any change.Please suggest

Comment: @user379080 What is your laptop? Mine has a key labelled `pause break` on the top row ...

Comment: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/keyboard-alternative-break-t3759101.html has some alternative key combinations for dell laptops without a break key

Comment: Thank you so much David!! I've used ctrl+Alt+Pause..it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

As DavidPostil mentioned, https://pcreview.co.uk/forums/keyboard-alternative-break-t3759101.html has some other options. One that worked for my Dell Inspiron was `CTRL ALT FN B` - B as break ;)